# Ninject bindings for a dispatcher implementation of an interface

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container

I have an interface:

```
public interface IService
{
    void DoStuff(int parm1, string parm2, Guid gimmeABreakItsAnExampleK);
}
```

I'd like to configure Ninject (v3) bindings so that I can have a "dispatcher" shuffle method calls out to multiple instances of `IService`, like so:

```
public sealed class DispatcherService : IService
{
    private IEnumerable<IService> _children;

    public DispatcherService(IEnumerable<IService> children)
    {
        this._children = children.ToList();
    }

    public void DoStuff(int parm1, string parm2, Guid gimmeABreakItsAnExampleK)
    {
        foreach(var child in this._children)
        {
            child.DoStuff(parm1, parm2, gimmeABreakItsAnExampleK);
        }
    }
}
```

However, my bindings, that look like this, wind up throwing an exception at runtime indicating a cyclic dependency:

```
this.Bind<IService>().To<DispatcherService>();

this.Bind<IService>().To<SomeOtherService>()
    .WhenInjectedExactlyInto<DispatcherService>();
this.Bind<IService>().To<YetAnotherService>()
    .WhenInjectedExactlyInto<DispatcherService>();
```

Is this possible? If so, what am I doing wrong? Can the ninja escape this cyclical dependency doom?

Comment: Why do you need `WhenInjectedExactlyInto`, why not just `To`?

Comment: Because `WhenInjectedExactlyInto` prevents `SomeOtherService` and `YetAnotherService` from being injected into anything but `DispatcherService`. I've used a similar approach to "wrap" (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752674/dependency-injection-how-to-configure-interface-bindings-for-wrapping), but I'm trying to get it working for the multi-injection case.

Comment: Have you looked at the various Event Broker extensions - they all do the stuff your examples do in great depth. OK, you said it was just an example, I'll be quiet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dispatcher is the *only* IService which is going to take a list of IServices as a parameter, this does work (I tested):

```
kernel.Bind<IService>().To<DispatcherService>().When(x => x.IsUnique);
this.Bind<IService>().To<SomeOtherService>()
    .WhenInjectedExactlyInto<DispatcherService>();
this.Bind<IService>().To<YetAnotherService>()
    .WhenInjectedExactlyInto<DispatcherService>();
```

The reason that `When` clause works for this case is that the `IsUnique` field of `IRequest` gets set to `true` when your constructor calls for a single instance of a service. Since your `DispatcherService` calls for an `IEnumerable`, the value is `false` when activating the `DispatcherService`. That prevents the circular dependency from happening.

Really, any correct way of telling the kernel not to not try to inject the DispatcherService into itself would work (this is just a potentially useful example).

Edit: The more explicit way of simply short circuiting your circular dependency appears to be this:

```
kernel.Bind<IService>().To<DispatcherService>().When(
   request => request.Target.Member.DeclaringType != typeof (DispatcherService));
```

Comment: Thank you, good sir! If you can update your answer to include some information on the `IsUnique` flag of `IRequest`, the answer and bounty goes to you.

Comment: @FMM Thanks. I hope my explanation isn't too clumsy :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! The single-instance versus multiple-instance thing isn't immediately apparent from the name `IsUnique`, IMHO.

Comment: I agree `request.IsUnique` reads as if it should imply something other than "true if the request should return a unique result" :)

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that I'm not that familiar with the Ninject API, but I think this would do the trick:

```
kernel.Bind<IService>().To<DispatcherService>();   

kernel.Bind<IEnumerable<IService>>().ToMethod(() => new IService[]
{
    kernel.Get<SomeOtherService>(),
    kernel.Get<YetAnotherService>(),
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Still causes a cyclical dependency. Using `IService[]` instead of `IEnumerable<IService>` has no impact, either.

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I understand why (but not sure how to solve this in Ninject). Ninject allows multiple calls to `Bind<IService>()` with different implementations, and Ninject will use them all to resolve the collection. (this is a feature most containers have and it is something I don't like very much). I think this overrides your manual `IEnumerable<IService>` registration. I think the trick is to register an `IList<IService>` or `IService[]` and let your `DispatcherService` depend directly on this `IList<IService>` or `IService[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get rid of IService in the DispatcherService and call it IDispatcherService and make the called services (receivers) implement IService?

Answer (score 0):

You could segregate the two subsets (either Dispatcher or the recievers) out of the way by making one of them a Named Binding, and then use the name as a way to feed one to the other (either via a `NamedAttribute` or in your wiring)

Comment: Code example? It also sounds like the `DispatcherService` constructor would then need Ninject-specific attributes, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Sorry, too busy this moment - ping again if you can't sort it without an example. Have a look on the wiki for named bindings examples...